# Combine multiple bootstrap classes into one SASS class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

In a form I have rows of form-groups with each having a label and form-control element.

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-xs-2 col-md-3">Text</label>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Labels use classes: 'col-xs-2 col-md-3' and form-controls: 'col-xs-10 col-md-9'

Is it possible to combine the two 'col' classes of the label element into one class in sass? Something like this:

```
.label-width{
   .col-xs-2
   .col-md-3
}
```

Giving me:

```
<label class="label-width">Text</label>
```

Which then I could control with a sass variable such as: '$labelColumnWidth: 2' to give me a quick way to set label widths for all rows. Something like this:

```
$labelColumnWidth: 2
.label-width{
   .col-xs-#{$labelColumnWidth}
   .col-md-#{$labelColumnWidth}
}
```

I would like to use the bootstrap classes for column spacing but able to control them with sass variables to quickly change the layout of the form. Possible?

Answer (score 10):

Even though it is not a good practice, you should be able to do this via `@extend`. In your case, your code should look like this:

```
.label-width{
   @extend .col-xs-2
   @extend .col-md-3
}
```

Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) if you need more explanation.

Comment: Trying the above solution I get: ".label-width" failed to @extend ".col-sm-3", The selector ".col-sm-3" was not found.

Comment: Apparently `@extend` works if the classes are in the same directive: http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_in_directives

Comment: Why is it bad practice?

Comment: Just wondering because if there are a lot of places where you are centering content, you could create a class like 

`.myCenter{
   @extend .d-flex
   @extend .flex-column
   @extend .justify-content-center
}`

and then you would have a reusable class which seems like better practice

Comment: @Sam I believe some people consider it to be bad practice because it's often used carelessly and can then create additional, unexpected rules. However, it's not unilaterally bad practice, you just need to know how it works in order to use it most efficiently:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/extending-in-sass-without-mess/

Comment: If you are using Angular, make sure to add this in `styles.scss` file or one of the root file

Answer (score 6):

### you can extend multiple class using multiple way like:

Way 1

```
.my-class {
   @extend .class1;
   @extend .class2;
   .
   .
   .
   @extend .classn;
}
```

**way 2**

one another way is you can extend multiple class in an single line here example

```
.my-class {
   @extend #{'.class1', '.class2', ... , '.classn'}
}
```

Know more details: [Sass official document](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

**Thanks**